# how to pass data to navigation header in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a cart icon as a header-right button for almost all screens. I am using react-navigation5.
I want to update the badge count on that button from my components.
Any possible way to achieve it without using redux or flux library?
following is my code for example:

route.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { Home, Cart, Wishlist, Login, Signup, Contact, Profile, Search } from './scenes';
import { Primary, Secondary } from './assets/color';
import { HeaderButton } from './components'
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function Route() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Profile" screenOptions={({ navigation, route }) =>({ headerRight:()=>(<HeaderButton navigation={navigation} nav='Cart'/>)})}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Cart" component={Cart} options={{headerRight:null}}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
);
}

export default Route;
```

headerButton.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Button, Icon, Badge, Text } from 'native-base';
import { Primary, Danger } from '../../assets/color'
export class HeaderButton extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <>
            <Button rounded transparent onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.push('Cart')}>
                <Icon type='MaterialIcons' name='shopping-cart' style={{color:Primary,right:6,top:2}}/>
            </Button>
           <Text>{this.props.count}</Text>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

home.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Button, Icon, Badge, Text } from 'native-base';
import { Primary, Danger } from '../../assets/color'
export class Home extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            count:1
        }
    }
    addToCart=()=>{
        var varcount=this.state.count;
        varcount=varcount+1;
        this.setState({count:varcount})
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <Button onPress={this.addToCart}>
            <Text>Add to cart</Text>
            </Button>

        );
    }
}
```

Whenever count is changed in the app it must be reflected in headerbutton component which is in route.js as headerRight

Comment: Hi @Karishma Kavankar, where you import the HeaderButton?

Comment: for example if you want to add the header right button into home page. you should import the component first.  import HeaderButton from "../path/tofile";

Comment: then your component should like <HeaderButton badgeCount={this.state.count} /> . then get count like "this.props.count"

Comment: i have imported headerButton in route.js as my headerbutton is common in almost all UI I have included it in route screenOptions. Please check route.js

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it by myself, using passing parameters from parent to child and vise versa.
The following are the changes I have made in my code.

route.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { Home, Cart, Wishlist, Login, Signup, Contact, Profile, Search } from './scenes';
import { Primary, Secondary } from './assets/color';
import { HeaderButton } from './components'
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function Route() {
   const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
     const onCount=(value)=>{
        setCount(value);
        console.log(count, value);
    }
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Profile" screenOptions={({ navigation, route }) =>({ headerRight:props =>(<HeaderButton navigation={navigation} nav='Cart' {...props} badgeCount={count}/>)})}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Cart" component={Cart} options={{headerRight:null}}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
);
}

export default Route;
```

headerButton.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Button, Icon, Badge, Text } from 'native-base';
import { Primary, Danger } from '../../assets/color'
export class HeaderButton extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <>
            <Button rounded transparent onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.push('Cart')}>
                <Icon type='MaterialIcons' name='shopping-cart' style={{color:Primary,right:6,top:2}}/>
            </Button>
           <Text>{this.props.badgeCount}</Text>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

home.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Button, Icon, Badge, Text } from 'native-base';
import { Primary, Danger } from '../../assets/color'
export class Home extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            count:1
        }
    }
    addToCart=()=>{
        var varcount=this.state.count;
        varcount=varcount+1;
        this.setState({count:varcount})
        this.props.onCountChange(this.state.count);

    }
    render(){
        return(
            <Button onPress={this.addToCart}>
            <Text>Add to cart</Text>
            </Button>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not mention where did you define "onCountChange" and what is it doing. I am in similar situation but your answer is not able to solve it unless you post adequate code. Why did you rename "count" to "badgeCount" and how did you pass it to HeaderButton component is also not clear.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you call the `addToCart`, you should add parenthesis to it since it has a function value, it should be `addToCart()`.
Also whenevery you call `addToCart()` The value will not change because the scope the `varcount` is only local, I suggest you make it global so it will not reset the value